# Understanding input voltage noise of AD8232

Tags: noise, datasheet, instrumentation-amplifier

[AD8232](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8232.pdf) has a built-in instrumentation amplifier with a fixed gain of 100. I am interested in using this device for amplifying EEG signals. Page 3 of the linked datasheet describes input voltage noise of the in-amp:

[image]

I'm not sure how to interpret these figures. Does Vpp-noise correspond to the actual input noise at gain=100, or should I multiply these values by a factor of 100?

Comment: This would be an acceptable noise level for ECG, but not EEG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually noise specs are as if it were all added to the input.  You even said yourself these are *input voltage* noise values.  I haven't looked at the datasheet other than the snippet you quoted, but it seems quite clear and there appears to be no reason to believe these figures aren't what they are labeled as.

Comment: This would be an acceptable noise level for ECG